# How can I read all methods using VBA

Tags: c#, .net, vba

I want to read all methods as well as the methods for current cursor location of a cs file using VBA macro.

Suppose I call macro from a specific line, then that macro should return me the method name for that selected position.

```
10: void test()
11: {
12: 
13:
14: }
```

So in the above code, if I call macro from line 10 to 14, I should get "test" (method name) as result.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you need. Can you explain better? Thanks

Comment: @ Marco - Please check the updated description.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert C# code to Visual Basic code using a converter (you can find plenty) and keywords like sub and function mean methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Lajos Arpad: I want to read the methods using VBA.. its not about conversion of C# to VB.